# Checking to see if 2 jquery ui datepickers have value to perform function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to check and see if 2 jquery ui datepickers have a value, if they do, perform a function, if not, to do nothing.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {

        }
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {

        }
    });
```

I think I need to use the callbacks to see if a date has been selected, but I'm stuck on how to check those callbacks to see if they have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using the `getDate` method of jquery ui datepicker. It returns `null` if there is no date selected.

```
$("#datepicker,#datepicker2").datepicker({
   onSelect: checkDates
});

function checkDates () {
    var ok = $('.hasDatepicker')
                       .filter( function() { 
                                   return $(this).datepicker('getDate') !== null
                              })
                       .length == 2;
      if (ok === true) {
        // doSomething 
      }     
}
```

datepicker have the "`hasdatepicker`" css class added on construct so `$('.hasDatepicker')` return all datepickers, then filter the result to get an array of item with a `date !== null`, then compare length to know if they are all filled.

You can replace `2` by `$('.hasDatepicker').length` if you want to check if all datepicker have a date selected.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hk8q20nj/)

Comment: Thank you so much! That's perfect, that's such a better way than I was trying to do it.